# Access all instances of a class while debugging

Tags: python, debugging, pydev

Is there a way in python\pydev to see and access instances of a certain class while debugging?
For instance, if I define `SomeClass` and various modules in a single python interpreter script instantiate this class, is there a way to see how many such instances exist in the interpreter and to access their attributes in a central fashion, without coercing the code to hold references to them from a single location (such as the module where the class is defined)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could find all such objects using [gc.get_objects()](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.get_objects):

For example, if you define `Foo` class in module `othermod.py`:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

f2 = Foo()
```

then you can count all instances of `Foo` in script `script.py` like this:

```
import gc
import othermod

f = othermod.Foo()

objs = gc.get_objects()
# print(len(objs))
# 3519

print(len([obj for obj in objs if isinstance(obj,othermod.Foo)]))
# 2
```

Caveat: `gc.get_objects` does not track instances of atomic types (like `int` or `str`), but it sounds like that is not the kind of object you want to track.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use [`objgraph`](http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/) module:

```
In [1]: class A(object): pass

In [2]: class B: pass

In [3]: test1 = [A() for i in range(3)]

In [4]: test2 = [A() for i in range(3)]

In [5]: test3 = [B() for i in range(5)]

In [6]: import objgraph

In [7]: objgraph.by_type('A')
Out[7]:
[<__main__.A at 0x2ccc130>,
 <__main__.A at 0x2ccc150>,
 <__main__.A at 0x2ccc170>,
 <__main__.A at 0x2cbb790>,
 <__main__.A at 0x2cbb1b0>,
 <__main__.A at 0x2cbb7f0>]
```

But it will not work for old-style classes:

```
In [8]: objgraph.by_type('B')
Out[8]: []
```

`objgraph` uses info from garbage collector, like in [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu) answer.